# how to understand this interface Executor example in Java API docs

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor, executor

Can anyone help to explain this piece of code in details?

```
 class SerialExecutor implements Executor {
   final Queue<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayDeque<Runnable>();
   final Executor executor;
   Runnable active;

   SerialExecutor(Executor executor) {
     this.executor = executor;
   }

   public synchronized void execute(final Runnable r) {
     tasks.offer(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         try {
           r.run();
         } finally {
           scheduleNext();
         }
       }
     });
     if (active == null) {
       scheduleNext();
     }
   }

   protected synchronized void scheduleNext() {
     if ((active = tasks.poll()) != null) {
       executor.execute(active);
     }
   }
 }
```

I am learning java concurrent programming. When i was looking into the piece of code, I feel lost. There are mainly two points confused me:

1. why define `Executor executor` inside Executor, how this works?
2. in `public synchronized void execute(final Runnable r)` it create `new Runnable(){}` and in these Runnable, it call Runnable r.run()? what is this?

Comment: Did you read the bit before the code that tells you what the code is about? "The executor below serializes the submission of tasks to a second executor, illustrating a composite executor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why define Executor executor inside Executor, how this works?

The `SerialExecutor` is a wrapper implementation which uses the decorator pattern. You can instantiate it with any implementation of the `Executor` interface or you can pass it as an argument where an `Executor` is expected.

Ex:-

```
SerialExecutor se = new SerialExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
Executor anotherExecutor = se;
```

See the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class Java API Documentation for more information

> 2. In `public synchronized void execute(final Runnable r)` it create new `Runnable(){}` and in these Runnable, it call Runnable `r.run()?` what is this?

Inside the above method the `r.run()` is invoked in a new `Runnable` instance because at the end of calling `r.run()` in finally block the `scheduleNext()` method is required to be called.